# How to write a working rc.d script for OpenBSD to launch a ruby program that lives in /sbin/?

Tags: openbsd, rc.d

This is everything that I've done: 
I wrote the `rc.d/` script, it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

daemon="/usr/local/sbin/dynaruby"
name="dynaruby"

. /etc/rc.d/rc.subr

rc_cmd $1
```

The program needs an environment variable to work. I tried setting it up following the man page of `rc.d`. It says to create an entry in `login.conf`, so I did, and that looks like this:

```
dynaruby:\
        :setenv=DYNARUBY_KEY="BupCxeBEflVyNK05ypuz25bXuoRc9Rg61qKnOBohyH0=,Xwsirr99KDqkz3Ncytn2AA==":\
        :tc=default:
```

I also did `cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf` for good measure, but still when I do `rcctl reload/start dynaruby` I always get `dynaruby(failed)`. I tried having a file entry in `/etc/login.conf.d/` without `:tc=default:` (tried both `:tc=daemon:` and nothing at all) instead of having it inside the main `login.conf` but with the same results. Any insight on how I could debug this further would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to say that I also added the service in `/etc/rc.conf.local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to force the env variable into the script by overriding the default `rc_start`

```
#!/bin/ksh

daemon="/usr/local/sbin/dynaruby"

. /etc/rc.d/rc.subr 
  
 rc_start() { 
 export DYNARUBY_KEY="YOUR,KEY" 
 exec /usr/local/sbin/dynaruby & 
 } 
 rc_cmd $1
```

This is not the intended way to do this, but I guess it works. Without `exec` the program will run fine until the `rc.d` framework kills it with error  `Timeout: No process found`. This might be fixed by overriding the `pexp` too, but I found just using `exec / &` to be the easiest.